# The type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

I have issues with SqlDataReader. I get the error "The type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' has no constructors defined" when I try running the page. My intention here is to return a string value 0 if the user has not had access or 1 when the user has assess. Below is my code snippet.

```
public string CheckAssess(string emailAddress, string columnName)
{
    string chkAssess;
    SqlDataReader readAssess;
    readAssess = new SqlDataReader();

    string MgrAssessQry = "SELECT '"+columnName+"' FROM tblAllUsers";
    MgrAssessQry += " WHERE email ='" + emailAddress + "'";

    SqlCommand cmdReadAssess = new SqlCommand(MgrAssessQry, cn);
    cn.Open();
    readAssess = cmdReadAssess.ExecuteReader();

    while(readAssess.Read())
    {
        // Add the rows
       chkAssess = readAssess["IsAssessMgr"].ToString();
    }

    return chkAssess;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. Also, beware constructing queries using string concatenation because it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks: use SQL parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
public string CheckAssess(string emailAddress, string columnName)
{
    string chkAssess;

    string MgrAssessQry = "SELECT '"+columnName+"' FROM tblAllUsers";
    MgrAssessQry += " WHERE email ='" + emailAddress + "'";

    SqlCommand cmdReadAssess = new SqlCommand(MgrAssessQry, cn);
    cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader readAssess = cmdReadAssess.ExecuteReader();

    while(readAssess.Read())
    {
        // Add the rows
       chkAssess = readAssess["IsAssessMgr"].ToString();
    }

    return chkAssess;
}
```

I have changed your SqlDataReader instantiation to the line where you execute the query
Same way like in this example from MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Remove New from SqlDataReader Declaration.

Try this:

Change this

```
SqlDataReader readAssess;
    readAssess = new SqlDataReader();
```

to

```
SqlDataReader readAssess;
```

[**SqlDataReader**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The [**SqlDataReader**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class has no constructors, rewrite your code to following:

```
public string CheckAssess(string emailAddress, string columnName)
{
    string chkAssess;
    SqlDataReader readAssess;
    string MgrAssessQry = "SELECT '"+columnName+"' FROM tblAllUsers WHERE email ='" + emailAddress + "'";
    SqlCommand cmdReadAssess = new SqlCommand(MgrAssessQry, cn);

    cn.Open();
    readAssess = cmdReadAssess.ExecuteReader();

    while(readAssess.Read())
    {
        chkAssess = readAssess["IsAssessMgr"].ToString();
    }

    return chkAssess;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chang your

```
 readAssess = new SqlDataReader ();

 readAssess = cmdReadAssess.ExecuteReader();
```

to

```
 SqlDataReader readAssess= cmdReadAssess.ExecuteReader();
```

[**SqlDataReader Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

Comment: This won't compile because `readAssess` is already defined with the proper type. The exception doesn't even occur at this line

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thankyou i have updated .Please have a look

Answer (score -1):

```
I had the same problem. I resolved by a simple way like this.

SqlDataReader read = null;
and to check 'read' has row or not
if(read.HasRows)
{
   while(read.Read()){}
}


So please see this your code.

public string CheckAssess(string emailAddress, string columnName)
{
    string chkAssess;
    SqlDataReader readAssess;
    readAssess = null; // this from my comments

    string MgrAssessQry = "SELECT '"+columnName+"' FROM tblAllUsers";
    MgrAssessQry += " WHERE email ='" + emailAddress + "'";

    SqlCommand cmdReadAssess = new SqlCommand(MgrAssessQry, cn);
    cn.Open();
    readAssess = cmdReadAssess.ExecuteReader();

    if(readAssess.HasRows && readAssess != null) // this from my comments
    {
       while(readAssess.Read())
       {
          // Add the rows
          chkAssess = readAssess["IsAssessMgr"].ToString();
       }
     }

     return chkAssess;
 }

 // I hope this code would help you.
```